# Efficiently importing XPM matrix data into Mathematica

Tags: import, sparse-arrays, chemistry, streams

The [XPM file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap) is an image file format.  Although it is primarily intended for icon pixmaps, it can also be used to store matrix data.  For example, the [GROMACS](http://www.gromacs.org/) chemical simulation package uses it in the program [g_hbond](http://manual.gromacs.org/online/g_hbond.html) to export hydrogen bond existence matrices.

A sample XPM file, generated by **g_hbond** is below:

```
/* XPM */
/* Generated by g_hbond_d */
/* This file can be converted to EPS by the GROMACS program xpm2ps */
/* title:   "Hydrogen Bond Existence Map" */
/* legend:  "Hydrogen Bonds" */
/* x-label: "Time (ps)" */
/* y-label: "Hydrogen Bond Index" */
/* type:    "Discrete" */
static char *gromacs_xpm[] = {
"201 2   2 1",
"   c #FFFFFF " /* "None" */,
"o  c #FF0000 " /* "Present" */,
/* x-axis:  0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 2 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 3 3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5 3.6 3.7 3.8 3.9 4 4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5 4.6 4.7 4.8 4.9 5 5.1 5.2 5.3 5.4 5.5 5.6 5.7 5.8 5.9 6 6.1 6.2 6.3 6.4 6.5 6.6 6.7 6.8 6.9 7 7.1 7.2 7.3 7.4 7.5 7.6 7.7 7.8 7.9 */
/* x-axis:  8 8.1 8.2 8.3 8.4 8.5 8.6 8.7 8.8 8.9 9 9.1 9.2 9.3 9.4 9.5 9.6 9.7 9.8 9.9 10 10.1 10.2 10.3 10.4 10.5 10.6 10.7 10.8 10.9 11 11.1 11.2 11.3 11.4 11.5 11.6 11.7 11.8 11.9 12 12.1 12.2 12.3 12.4 12.5 12.6 12.7 12.8 12.9 13 13.1 13.2 13.3 13.4 13.5 13.6 13.7 13.8 13.9 14 14.1 14.2 14.3 14.4 14.5 14.6 14.7 14.8 14.9 15 15.1 15.2 15.3 15.4 15.5 15.6 15.7 15.8 15.9 */
/* x-axis:  16 16.1 16.2 16.3 16.4 16.5 16.6 16.7 16.8 16.9 17 17.1 17.2 17.3 17.4 17.5 17.6 17.7 17.8 17.9 18 18.1 18.2 18.3 18.4 18.5 18.6 18.7 18.8 18.9 19 19.1 19.2 19.3 19.4 19.5 19.6 19.7 19.8 19.9 20 0 */
/* y-axis:  0 1 0 */
"ooooooooooooooo oooooooooooooooooooo oo oooo ooooooooooo  oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo   o oooooooooooooooo ooo oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo ooooo ooo  oooooo  o oooooooo   ooooo oooooo",
"                                                                                                                                                                               o o                       "
```

This file is also available [here, on Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6cOQue8IYJCRzRMVFZDTUMwX1U/edit?pli=1).

The last two lines provide the matrix data. If there is an `"o"` character, then that particular hydrogen bond (each line represents a different hydrogen bond) exists at that time.

Do you know if there are any functions or add-on packages for Mathematica that can read in XPM files?  In particular, I would like to read in the last two lines:

```
"ooooooooooooooo oooooooooooooooooooo oo oooo ooooooooooo  oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo   o oooooooooooooooo ooo oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo ooooo ooo  oooooo  o oooooooo   ooooo oooooo",
"                                                                                                                                                                               o o                       "
```

and store the result as a `List`, `Array`, or `SparseArray`.  Probably `SparseArray` would be desirable because the values in the matrix are binary -- a particular hydrogen bond either exists at a certain time or it doesn't.  Also, it doesn't really matter what character we use to represent existence (in the above, they use `"o"`) and absence (in the above, they use `" "`).

Do you have any advice on the best way to read in this data?  The sample above is only very small; however, the files can get *much* larger, so I probably will not be able to import the entire file at once using `Import`.  Probably I will have to read the file piecewise, perhaps using `Stream`.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a string processing way of extracting the "x-axis" data from the XPM file that you gave. I'll assume that you have already imported the all of the file's records into the string `text` - e.g. using `text = Import[filename,"String"]`, though I haven't tested this as I actually copied (then pasted into an empty string) the contents of the XPM file quoted in the OP's question.

```
text // StringCases[#, 
  "/* x-axis:" ~~ Whitespace ~~ 
  s : Shortest[(NumberString ~~ Whitespace) ..] ~~ 
  "*/" :> (ImportString[s, "Table"] // Flatten)] &
```

You can extract the "ooo..." line(s) as follows

```
text // StringCases[#, "\"" ~~ ("o" | Whitespace) .. ~~ "\""] &
```

String matching/processing tricks like this are very useful for importing structured data.